# How to prove that $L^- \le c \le L^+$. Where $c$ is a limit point and $L^-$ and $L^+$ are the limit inferior and limit superior respectively.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I have been trying to prove this exercise for way too long and am nowhere near a proof. I have asked this question before and haven't got a satisfactory answer. This could be my own fault for not defining everything properly.

The book I am learning from(Analysis $1$ by Tao) defines the limit superior and limit inferior as follows. Some people like using the notation used in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior). The wikipedia article is exactly the same as the following definitions.

The following is how the book defines limit superior and limit inferior.

---

Sequence of supremums: Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Define a new sequence $(a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty$ by $a^+_k:=\sup ((a_n)_{n=k}^\infty)$.

Limit superior: The limit superior of a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is defined to be $\inf ((a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty)$

Sequence of infimums: Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Define a new sequence $(a^-_N)_{N=m}^\infty$ by $a^-_k:=\inf ((a_n)_{n=k}^\infty)$.

Limit inferior: The limit inferior of a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is defined to be $\sup((a^-_N)_{N=m}^\infty)$.

Limit point: Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $c$ be a real number. Then $c$ is said to be a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ and for every $N\ge m$, there exists an $n\ge N$ such that $|a_n-c|<\varepsilon$.

---

The exercise asks to prove that if $c$ is a limit point of a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. And $L^-$ and $L^+$ are the limit inferior and limit superior respectively, then $L^-\le c \le L^+$.

I have previously been suggested proofs using subsequences. The only problem is that the book hasn't introduced subsequences yet. Which means that the proof shouldn't involve subsequences. Could someone guide me on how to prove this statement?

Comment: If you don't know about subsequences, what is a limit point for you?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I will update the post with the definition of limit point provided in the book right now.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A \le a_n \le B$ for a infinitely many $n$, then we must have
$\liminf_n a_n \le B$ and $\limsup_n a_n \ge A$.

If $c$ is a limit point of $a_n$, pick some $\epsilon >0$ then
$c-\epsilon < a_n < c+ \epsilon$ infinitely often. Hence
$\liminf_n a_n \le c+ \epsilon$ and similarly $\limsup a_n \ge c-\epsilon$.

Since this is true for any $\epsilon>0$, the result follows.

Comment: Could you tell me what is $A$ and $B$?

Comment: In the above they are $c-\epsilon, c+ \epsilon$ respectively.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: That is a very nice solution. I came back to this problem months later and now understand the proof. I was just hung up on a few aspects and didn't think them through. For example, I couldn't understand why $c - \varepsilon < a_n < c + \varepsilon$. But using the results that $|a - b| = |b - a|$ and $a \le |a|$, I proved that inequality. Thank you very much! This is one problem I have spent the longest time working on so far!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences $(c-a_N^-)$ and $(a_N^+-c)$. Use the fact that the limit of a convergent nonnegative sequence is also nonnegative, the result follows.

Comment: But $a^-_N$ and $a^+_N$ could be $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively. In which case, the sequences don't make any sense.

Comment: If $c$ exists then talk three sequences are bounded.

Comment: Totally forgot that they would be bounded. I will think this through and get back to you if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is this right? Consider the sequence $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,\dots$. But clearly $c=1<\infty$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Good counterexample I tried thinking of one and completely blanked.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess that could be the contradiction. If $c> L^+$ where $L^+$ is finite, then using a previous result, we would have that $c> \sup(a_n)$. This implies that the sequence is bounded. But since the sequence was arbitrary, this is a contradiction. Is that correct? I have been working for too long so I might not be thinking straight right now.

Comment: $c>\sup(a_n)$ needn’t be valid. The limsup may be smaller. You can write down obvious examples. But if $c>L^+$, then there are $a_n$ with $n$ arbitrarily large and $a_n>L^+$. Is this possible?